# Python elasticsearch.helpers.scan example

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Can someone provide scan API example of python elasticsearch helpers client?

```
res = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(....)
```

How can i get all results from elasticsearch with res object?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/6.0.0/helpers.html#scan) includes an example, although if I'm reading it right, `helpers.scan` by default sets `search_type=scan`, which was [removed in ES 5.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_scan_literal_removed). This causes the example code to fail with ES returning `No search type for [scan]`. We can amend this with `preserve_order=True` (I am however not sure about the performance implications here):

```
import elasticsearch
import elasticsearch.helpers
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()
results = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es,
    index="test_index",
    doc_type="my_document",
    preserve_order=True,
    query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
)

for item in results:
    print(item['_id'], item['_source']['name'])
```

This helper returns an object which you can iterate to obtain the actual results from the query.

`item` is of form

```
{'_index': <str>, '_type': <str>, '_id': <str>, '_score': <float or None>, '_source': {'key': val}, 'sort': [<int>]}
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'elasticsearch' has no attribute 'helpers'`  ??

Comment: @keithpjolley Yeah thanks, fixed. That error message could be a bit less misleading...